# Only load stylesheet on Widget pages

Tags: php, magento

How can I dynamically load stylesheets into the "head" section in Magento only on pages that include a custom Widget?

For my scripts I'm doing this:

```
if($this->getLayout()->getBlock('namespace_module_scripts')==false) {
    $block = $this->getLayout()
        ->createBlock('core/template', 'namespace_module_scripts')
        ->setTemplate('namespace/module/scripts.phtml');
    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('before_body_end')->insert($block);
}
```

This is the current content of `_prepareLayout()` in my Widget block class. I tried using the same method for styles, swapping `before_body_end` for `head`, and that worked great for placing Widget Instances or manually placing the block in my layout xml, however when inserting a widget inline in a Page's content the head section seems to be rendered prior to the Widget, and therefore my styles template can't be inserted into the head block.

My (hopefully) temporary solution is to load the styles on every page in my layout xml. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're SOL with widgets you're inserting into CMS pages via the

```
{{widget...}}}
```

tag.  Unlike instances, or adding it directly via a Package Layout XML update file, Magento appears to render these blocks on the fly.  That is, its not until `toHtml` is called on the CMSs content block that Magento instantiates a `{{widget...}}` block. By then the head block has already rendered, and manipulating it programmatically no longer has any effect.

Here's the approach I'd take.  It sounds adding javascript still works (which makes sense, as the CMS content block will be rendering before the `before_body_end` block.)  Look into techniques for [loading CSS files via Javascript](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss.shtml) (older link, google around if you want something web 2ish).  That way you can add a javascript block that can add a CSS file. This way all your code is still confined to the widget, and you still get validating html output.  It's a pretty common technique.

Other approaches include

1. Just added your styles to the document inline.  Bad HTML practices and all that (style aren't in the head), but you wouldn't be the first person to do this.
2. Having a block that's **always** added to the head, and contains conditional rendering logic.  Immediately prior to rendering, have it check the layout object for your widget (via the type) OR have it check if this request is for a CMS page, and if it is check CMS page's content for a directive (`{{widget...}}`) for rendering your widget.  If either is true, have CSS link rendered.  If it isn't, the link doesn't render.

Comment: Thanks Alan, I had a feeling you were going to be the one to answer this. I was hoping I could do something with an Observer, but haven't been successful with that (probably because I can't filter the output of toHtml prior to the head block loading). Loading styles with JS could be an option, thanks.

Comment: An event's a possibility too.  Hook into one of the page block's after or before redder events, (or the layout's after load) and do something like I suggested in #2.  Where you hook in is up to you, but the general idea (if you don't want the javascript approach) is to examine the state of the system, determine if your widget is, or will be, there and then [do something] to add the styles.